# carousel de radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

estou usando o plugin owl-carousel 2.0.0, para fazer um carousel de imagens de embalagens de produtos que são selecionáveis, através de um input radio, apenas uma embalagem deve ser selecionada, a estrutura deste carousel é a seguinte, o container é um `<label>` e dentro dele tem o `input[type=radio]` e a imagem do produto `<img>` quando clicar no item do carousel, que neste caso é o label, ele muda o estado do input radio para checked, eu quero pegar este evento e adicionar uma classe no label sempre que este input radio estiver checked, e quando eu selecionar outro botão de radio ele remove a classe do outro item e adiciona no atual.

eu fiz um pequeno script mas atualmente ele não faz bem o que eu quero, quando seleciono outro radio ele mantém a classe no label anterior, talvez seja a minha lógica que esteja errada. segue script:

http://jsfiddle.net/og7ee99s/2/

Comment: Copie o trecho do código aqui, se for grande, cite o trecho que está gerando dúvida, assim fica mais fácil a análise.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta retirar a classe de todos os labels antes. Assim deve funcionar:

```
$('input[name=pack]').on('click', function() {
   $('.owl-item').find('.product').removeClass('active');
   if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   }
});
```